# How many such polynomial exist?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, contest-math

> Find the number of second-degree polynomials $f(x)$ with integer coefficients and integer zeros for which $f(0)=2010$.

I got:

$$P(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \implies P(0) = c = 2010$$

Let $P(r_1, r_2) = 0$ thus, $r_1 + r_2 = -\frac{b}{a}$ and $r_1 \cdot r_2 = \frac{c}{a} = \frac{2010}{a}$.

Since: $2010 = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 67$ there are $10$ values for $a$ so $r_1r_2$ is an integer. That is:

$a \in (-67, -5, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 67)$.

But then since $r_1 + r_2 = -\frac{b}{a}$, $b$ has infinite values. so I cant solve the problem.

**HINTS ONLY PLEASE!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You've done most of the (non-combinatorial) thinking necessary here.  For any given $a$, it suffices to find all pairs of integers $r_1$ and $r_2$ such that
$$
r_1 \cdot r_2 = \frac{2010}{a}
$$
Or, in other words, find all triples of integers $r_1,r_2,a$ satisfying
$$
r_1 \cdot r_2 \cdot a = 2010
$$
From there, set
$$
b = -a(r_1 + r_2)
$$
Also, you're missing quite a few valid values for $a$; you should find that there are $2^5 = 32$ possibilities.

---

**Further Hint**

For any pair $r_1,r_2$ such that $r_1r_2$ divides $2010 = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 67$, there is a unique suitable polynomial with these roots.

The number of ways to divide the (multi)set 
$$
\{-1,-1,2,3,5,67\}
$$
into $3$ subsets is given by $\frac{1}{2}(3^6 + 3^4)$.

We can have a repeated root if $r_1 = r_2 = 1$ or $r_1 = r_2 = -1$, and exactly two associated polynomials. In all other cases, the two roots are distinct.  The corresponding polynomials were counted once in the above consideration, but all others were counted twice.

Comment: $r_1 r_2 a = 67 * 5 * 3 * 2$

Let $a = 67^{a_1} 5^{a_2} * 3^{a_3} * 2^{a_4}$. $2^4 = 16$ possibilities. But since each possibility can be negative. $2 \cdot 2^4 = 32$ possibilities. 

then $b$ should also have $2^5$ values for each value of $a$ right?

Comment: @Amad27 don't think about which values $b$ has.  If we find $r_1,r_2,$ and $a$, then the value of $b$ is determined.  Also, it's not clear what values $b$ can have given a particular $a$, but it **is** clear what values $r_1$ and $r_2$ can have given a particular $a$.

Comment: If $a=1$, there are $2^4$ solutions for $r_1, r_2$. same for $a=-1$ when $a=2$ $r_1 r_2 = 67*5*3$ $8$ solutions each. $r_1 r_2 = 67*5*2$ 8 solutions. $r_1 r_2 = 67*3*2$, 8 solutions, $r_1 r_2 = 5*3*2$, 8 solutions. When $r_1 r_2 = xyz$ 8 solutions,  $r_1 r_2 = xy$ there are 4 solutions. If $r_1 r_2 = x$ there are $2$ solutions. And then times $2$ for the negative complement.

$\sum = 2(4(8) + 6(4) + 16 + 2(8)) = 2(88) = 176$ solutions for $b$. 

But $2^5 * 176 = 5632$ thats incorrect.

Comment: @omon. Please advice a little more, I think I almost got it.

Comment: How should I fix the over counting?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $b$ cannot take infintely many values, since $r_1r_2=\frac{2010}{a}\leq2010$.

If $b$ gets too large, then $r_1+r_2$ gets to large.

If you want another hint, feel free to comment.

Comment: the answer is 653. But I got $32$ values for $a$, but I cant figure out $b$?

Comment: @Amad When $a=1$, then $r_1r_2=2010$ and $r_1+r_2=b$, therefore the number of different values for $b$ is the number of ways to write 2010 as a product of two integers.

Comment: @w, I posted this in Omnon. comment too: 

"If $a=1$, there are $2^4$ solutions for $r_1, r_2$. same for $a=-1$ when $a=2$ $r_1 r_2 = 67*5*3$ $8$ solutions each. $r_1 r_2 = 67*5*2$ 8 solutions. $r_1 r_2 = 67*3*2$, 8 solutions, $r_1 r_2 = 5*3*2$, 8 solutions. When $r_1 r_2 = xyz$ 8 solutions,  $r_1 r_2 = xy$ there are 4 solutions. If $r_1 r_2 = x$ there are $2$ solutions. And then times $2$ for the negative complement.

$\sum = 2(4(8) + 6(4) + 16 + 2(8)) = 2(88) = 176$ solutions for $b$. 

But $2^5 * 176 = 5632$ thats incorrect."